# I don't know why this error occurs in linux

Tags: beagleboneblack

An error occurred in the process of carrying out an ultrasonic distance measurement project using pru
i am trying to this code(https://github.com/luigif/hcsr04?files=1)

root@beaglebone:~# pasm -b hcsr04.p
-sh: pasm: command not found

I think that pasm is the command to create the PRU binary. I would appreciate it if you could tell me why this error occurred.
also can i use other method?,  please help me.

Comment: You either do not have the `pasm` utility installed, or it is located in a directory that is not in your `PATH`.

Comment: Please follow your link https://github.com/luigif/hcsr04?files=1 : The text says → pasm -b hcsr04.p ... PRU Assembler Version 0.84

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Install "pasm" utility in your system.
   [Read this for pasm installation.](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/PRU_Projects)
2. Cross compile your application using GCC.
   [Read this article for cross compilation.](https://github.com/hzeller/beagleg/issues/2)